Probability that an Exponential Random Variable Falls in Interval [n, n+1] where n is an Odd Integer
This is a problem found in Recitation 9 of MIT $6.041$. The problem is as follows:
"Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda>0$. Calculate the probability that $X$ belongs to one of the intervals $[n, n + 1]$ with $n$ odd."
The original solution computes the result by finding $P[n\leq X\leq n+1]$ using the CDF of the exponential random variable and summing over everything, which I understand. For reference, here's the solution:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P&=\sum_{\text{n is odd}}e^{-\lambda n}(1-e^{-\lambda}) \\ 
&= (1-e^{-\lambda})\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}e^{-\lambda(2k+1)} \\ 
&= (1-e^{-\lambda})e^{-\lambda}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(e^{-2\lambda})^k \\ 
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{1+e^{-\lambda}} \\ 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
But I don't understand why the following approach is wrong, which to me is just regrouping series and should be totally fine:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P&=\sum_{\text{n is odd}}e^{-\lambda n}(1-e^{-\lambda}) \\ 
&= e^{-\lambda}-e^{-2\lambda}+e^{-3\lambda}-e^{-4\lambda}+...\\ 
&= (e^{-\lambda}+e^{-3\lambda}+...)-(e^{-2\lambda}+e^{-4\lambda}+...) \\ 
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{1-e^{-2\lambda}} - \frac{e^{-2\lambda}}{1-e^{-2\lambda}} \\ 
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}-e^{-2\lambda}}{1-e^{-2\lambda}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I really want to understand what is happening here. Both methods are using the sum of an infinite geometric series and seems identical to me except for grouping. Thanks!

Hint. Did you calculate these for a given $\lambda$? Did you actually get something different?

Double Hint. Is your result reducible? ETA: It is worth checking that the series is in fact unconditionally convergent, however.

Both are correct and are actually equal. Simplify using difference of squares :)

Haha now it makes so much sense. Didn't thought of difference of squares. Thank you!
